# Hide/Disable "send to" menu of excel 2010

Tags: c#, excel-2010

```
application.ExecuteExcel4Macro("SHOW.TOOLBAR(\"Ribbon\",False)") ;

[here "application" is nothing but "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application"]
```

Above line hides complete ribbon (all menus) in excel.

Is there any way to hide/disable menus like `Open`,`New`,`Save` & `Send` etc in c#.